# Create discriminated union data from file/database

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I have a discriminated union for expressions like this one (EQ =; GT >; etc)

```
  (AND (OR (EQ X 0)
           (GT X 10))
       (OR (EQ Y 0)
           (GT Y 10)))
```

I want to create instances of DU from such expressions saved in file/database.
How do i do it? If it is not feasible, what is the best way to approach it in F#?

Daniel: these expressions are saved in prefix format (as above) as text and will be parsed in F#. Thanks.

Comment: Are these expressions stored as text that needs to be parsed or what?

Comment: Do you want to know how to model your AST?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to know how to model these expressions using DUs, here's one way:

```
type BinaryOp =
  | EQ
  | GT

type Expr =
  | And of Expr * Expr
  | Or of Expr * Expr
  | Binary of BinaryOp * Expr * Expr
  | Var of string
  | Value of obj

let expr = 
  And(
    Or(
      Binary(EQ, Var("X"), Value(0)),
      Binary(GT, Var("X"), Value(10))),
    Or(
      Binary(EQ, Var("Y"), Value(0)),
      Binary(GT, Var("Y"), Value(10))))
```

Now, this may be too "loose," i.e., it permits expressions like `And(Value(1), Value(2))`, which may not be valid according to your grammar. But this should give you an idea of how to approach it.

There are also some [good examples](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lexing_and_Parsing#Step_1%3a_Define_the_Abstract_Syntax_Tree) in the F# Programming wikibook.

If you need to parse these expressions, I highly recommend [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but here the DU instance is created literally, i.e. in source code. I need a function that can take strings like "(EQ X 10)" and "(OR (EQ Y 2) (LT A 3))" and return a DU instance.

Comment: You're asking for a full-fledged parser? Check out FParsec or the wikibooks page I linked to.

Comment: sorry for my poor writing and poor understanding of F#: i can parse the prefix syntax, but what functions to call to instantiate the DU.

Comment: The DU cases themselves are constructors. Does my example code not demonstrate how to do what you want?

Comment: i think i know what i was looking for now: i just came to realize that in your answer AND OR and Binary ARE the functions for that purpose. i was reading them only as type names.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience with me!

Comment: I finished off all my scotch and my fingernails are gone...but, you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's answer is good.  Here's a similar approach, along with a simple top-down parser built with active patterns:

```
type BinOp = | And | Or
type Comparison = | Gt | Eq

type Expr =
| BinOp of BinOp * Expr * Expr
| Comp of Comparison * string * int

module private Parsing = 
    // recognize and strip a leading literal 
    let (|Lit|_|) lit (s:string) =
        if s.StartsWith(lit) then Some(s.Substring lit.Length)
        else None

    // strip leading whitespace
    let (|NoWs|) (s:string) =
        s.TrimStart(' ', '\t', '\r', '\n')

    // parse a binary operator
    let (|BinOp|_|) = function
    | Lit "AND" r -> Some(And, r)
    | Lit "OR" r -> Some(Or, r)
    | _ -> None

    // parse a comparison operator
    let (|Comparison|_|) = function
    | Lit "GT" r -> Some(Gt, r)
    | Lit "EQ" r -> Some(Eq, r)
    | _ -> None

    // parse a variable (alphabetical characters only)
    let (|Var|_|) s =
        let m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, "^[a-zA-Z]+")
        if m.Success then
            Some(m.Value, s.Substring m.Value.Length)
        else
            None

    // parse an integer
    let (|Int|_|) s =
        let m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, @"^-?\d+")
        if m.Success then
            Some(int m.Value, s.Substring m.Value.Length)
        else
            None

    // parse an expression
    let rec (|Expr|_|) = function
    | NoWs (Lit "(" (BinOp (b, Expr(e1, Expr(e2, Lit ")" rest))))) -> 
        Some(BinOp(b, e1, e2), rest)
    | NoWs (Lit "(" (Comparison (c, NoWs (Var (v, NoWs (Int (i, Lit ")" rest))))))) ->
        Some(Comp(c, v, i), rest)
    | _ -> None

let parse = function
| Parsing.Expr(e, "") -> e
| s -> failwith (sprintf "Not a valid expression: %s" s)

let e = parse @"
    (AND (OR (EQ X 0)
             (GT X 10))
         (OR (EQ Y 0)
             (GT Y 10)))"
```

Comment: Thanks KVB, I just read about active pattern and found it interesting. I will use your answer as a template and try to extend from it.